# How do I negate this logical expression?

Tags: logic, logical-operators, boolean-logic

So, right now my code has something like this:

```
if(DateA <= utcNow || (DateA == null && DateB <= utcNow)) doSomething();
```

I want to do something like this now:

```
if(!InitialExpression) continue;
```

AFAIK, if `A || B`, the negation would be `!A && !B`.
But this doesn't work: `if(DateA > utcNow && (DateA != null || DateB > utcNow)) continue;`. 
When `DateA = null` and `DateB > utcNow` it should fall into the continue but it doesn't.

### Edit:

My mistake was assuming the opposite of `DateA <= utcNow` is `DateA > utcNow`. But it's `DateA == null || DateA > utcNow`

Comment: Are you looking for `else`? As in `if (thiscondition) dothis else dothat`?

Comment: Look up demorgans law

Comment: @MitchelPaulin Thanks! I knew that law, but when I looked at the Venn Diagrams I realized my mistake. See edit in question

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1 - use an `ELSE` statement

`if(DateA <= utcNow || (DateA == null && DateB <= utcNow)) 
{doSomething()
}else{
dpSomethingElse();`

- Option 2 - use `!` in the operator

`if(!(DateA <= utcNow || (DateA == null && DateB <= utcNow))) doSomethingElse();`

- Option 3 - negation - The condition of DataA not being null will need to go first. There is some context missing but assuming you want to negate the expression by ensuring that give preference to DateA if it is greater than utcNow, else check for DateB being greater then utcNow

`if((DateA != null && DateA > utcNow) || DateB > utcNow) doSomethingElse()`

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of `DateA <= utcNow || (DateA == null && DateB <= utcNow)` is

```
(DateA == null || DateA > utcNow) && (DateA != null || DateB == null || DateB > utcNow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic was pretty much alright @Felipe. Just that you overlooked a tiny aspect.
The negation of `<=` is not just `>` but it also includes a `NULL` value.just add these 2 conditionals along with an `OR` operator. This should work.

Check the updated statement below:

```
(DateA == null || DateA > utcNow) && (DateA != null || DateB == null || DateB > utcNow)
```